# Tomcat Clustering in Session Replication

Tags: tomcat, session-replication

When do we use session replication especially in context to Tomcat Clustering? I have read about it, but i haven't got enough resources to understand it as example. can you please explain it to me with some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Session Replication in a tomcat cluster is used to replicate the session information to all the nodes participating in the cluster so that when the node serving your request changes, your session data is persisted.

I believe tomcat's own documentation would be a great help to get you started.

Otherwise I found this to be a good read: https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-clustering